# Resource scanning with Java Reflections (upgrading from 0.9.x to 0.10.x)

Tags: java, reflections

I use the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library to list resources located in Java packages and I have the following code based on Reflections 0.9.x which works perfectly:

```
Reflections r = new Reflections("com.example.so", new ResourcesScanner());
Set<String> set = r.getResources(s -> s.contains("foo") && s.endsWith(".bar"))
    .stream()
    .map(s -> '/' + s)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(set);
```

Indeed, assuming the existence of the following resources in the classpath:

```
/com/example/so/foo.bar
/com/example/so/foo.baz
```

the output of this code is correct:

```
[/com/example/so/foo.bar]
```

Now I'm trying to upgrade Reflections to 0.10.x, but the API has been changed heavily:

1. `ResourcesScanner` is deprecated and should be replaced with `Scanners.Resources` (straightforward);
2. `Reflections.getResources(Predicate)` has been removed and I cannot find a direct replacement for it. There is an overload that takes a regex pattern, but I would like to avoid it because, IMHO, complex regexps are harder to mantain than equivalent Java predicates.

I tried the following new code, but, apart the regex `.*` that is totally useless, it does not work; in particular, the `Resources.filterResultsBy(Predicate)` method seems not filtering anything:

```
Reflections r = new Reflections("com.example.so", Scanners.Resources.filterResultsBy(s -> s.contains("foo") && s.endsWith(".bar")));
Set<String> set = r.getResources(".*").stream().map(s -> '/' + s).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(set);
```

Now the output is (wrong):

```
[/com/example/so/foo.bar, /com/example/so/foo.baz]
```

Am I missing something of the new API? Should I filter the set afterwards?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with a regex that matches just `foo.bar` such as `.*foo.*\.bar`? What happens then?

Comment: @DavidConrad the regex works, thanks, but, as I said, I would avoid regexps because, in the real scenarios, predicate can be more complex than this.